# How to Login to my account through java code

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code in which I am passing my existing user id and password and want that when I execute the code it should ask my user id and password and then authorize me to access the home page. I tried to do, but so far it asks for user id and password and after entering the credentials it shows me the login (html) page.

package test;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;



public class Api {

    private static final int MYTHREADS = 50;
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String user, pass;

        System.out.print("Enter your username:");
        user = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your Password:");
        pass = input.nextLine();

        if (user.equals("tester") && (pass.equals("12345")))
        {
            System.out.println("welcome");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("please try again!");
        }


        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);
        String[] apiList = {"https://example.com", };

        for (int i = 0; i < apiList.length; i++) {

            String url = apiList[i];
            Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(url);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        // Wait until all threads are finish

        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

        }
        System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");
    }

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final String url;

        MyRunnable(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
```

/*Error as implements java.lang.runnable.run */

@Override
                public void run() {

```
                String result = "";
                int code = 200;
                try {
                    URL siteURL = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    connection.connect();
                    code = connection.getResponseCode();
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    String base64 = null;
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" +base64);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(inputLine);                  
                    if (code == 200) {
                        result = "-> Successful <-\t" + "Code: " + code;
                        ;
                    } else {
                        result = "-> Unsuccessful <-\t" + "Code: " + code;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    result = "-> Sorry <-\t" + "Wrong domain - Exception: " + e.getMessage();

                }

                System.out.println(url + "\t\tStatus:" + result);

}
      } 
    }
```

Comment: well... you set user/password, but you don't use it ;-) Isn't there any better way to access that API?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: @Roland Could be a better way, I tried 2-3 but didn't get desired result so I tried to stick with this one. I haven't use my user/password! Can you please explain.

Comment: I see that you set the `user` and `password` variable to whatever is given to `System.in`, but you do not reference it afterwards. Your `base64`-variable is `null`, so: you did not use user/password yet...

Comment: use char[] instead of String for password, it is more secure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using javax.ws.rs.client.Client;

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basicBuilder().credentials(login, password).build();
client.register(feature);
```

Regarding you example I can't find where you setting your credentials to request

In your case maybe some authenticator can help:

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray());
}
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried with your suggestion but no luck. As you have mentioned you can't find " where you setting your credentials to request".I want (tried) it should ask for my credentials and directly authorize me to home page. Please let me know if I am making any mistake in it(which I am sure I am).

Comment: actually you have to set your login and password before doing a request. Please try using Authenticator